# Vector basic geometry

Tags: geometry

[image: vector problem]

So I have tried substituting and nothing would cancel out,  any ideas? 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notation:**    the following will use $AB$ for $| \overrightarrow{AB} |\;$, $\;\overrightarrow{AB} \cdot \overrightarrow{CD}\;$ for the dot product of two vectors, $AB \cdot \overrightarrow{CD}\;$ for the multiplication of a vector $\overrightarrow{CD}\;$ by a scalar $AB\;$, and $AB \cdot CD$ for the regular scalar multiplication. Note that vector magnitudes are *un*signed, so that for example $DA+DB=AB$ iff point $D$ is between $A$ and $B$.

**Primer:**    it is (assumed to be) known that $AB^2 = \overrightarrow{AB} \cdot \overrightarrow{AB}$, that the dot product is distributive vs. vector addition, and that for $D$ between $A$ and $B$ it holds true that $\overrightarrow{DA} = \frac{AD}{AB} \cdot \overrightarrow{BA}$.

**Proof:**   Squaring the hinted identities:

$$
AC^2 = AD^2 + DC^2 + 2\; \overrightarrow{AD} \cdot \overrightarrow{DC} \tag{1}
$$
$$
BC^2 = BD^2 + DC^2 + 2\; \overrightarrow{BD} \cdot \overrightarrow{DC} \tag{2}
$$

Multiplying $(1)$ by $DB$ and $(2)$ by $AD$ then adding together:

$$
\begin{align}
AC^2 \cdot DB + BC^2 \cdot AD & = AD^2 \cdot DB + BD^2 \cdot DA \\ & \qquad + DC^2 \cdot DB + DC^2 \cdot AD \\ & \qquad + 2\;(DB \cdot \overrightarrow{AD} + AD \cdot \overrightarrow{BD}) \cdot \overrightarrow{DC} \\
 & = AD \cdot DB \cdot (AD + BD) \\ & \qquad + DC^2 \cdot (DB + AD) \\ & \qquad + 2\; \frac{DB \cdot AD}{AB} \cdot (\overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{BA}) \cdot \overrightarrow{DC} \\
 & = AD \cdot DB \cdot AB + CD^2 \cdot AB
\end{align}
$$

The latter gives the original relation, and therefore proves it.

(As a side comment, the relation is equivalent to [Stewart's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem#Theorem), whose most common proof uses the law of cosines rather than vectors, though the above mirrors that quite closely.)